Mutation Observer not triggering on IOS Mobile
I've developed this Mutation Observer to monitor changes in a Shopify cart drawer. The logic is quite simple:
function callback(mutationList) {
  console.log("Observer callback fired");
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      var cartDrawerBody = document.querySelector("div.cart-drawer__body");
      if (cartDrawerBody) {
        var children = cartDrawerBody.querySelectorAll(".cart-item__container").length;
        if (children > 0) {
          observer.disconnect(); // Disconnect the observer to prevent loop
          adjustPadding();
          var cartDrawerFooter = document.querySelector(".cart-drawer__footer");
          if (!cartDrawerFooter) {
            console.log("No footer found");
            return;
          }
          if (!$(cartDrawerFooter).find(".post-footer-content").length) {
            var postFooterContent = $(`
              <div class="post-footer-content">
                <!-- Simplified content -->
                <div class="post-footer-row">Content</div>
              </div>
            `);
            $(cartDrawerFooter).append(postFooterContent);
            console.log("Content appended to footer");
          } else {
            console.log("Content already exists in footer, not appending");
          }
          observer.observe(document.querySelector("#cd-cart"), {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterData: true,
          });
        } else {
          console.log("no children to append");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("no body");
      }
    }
  }
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(cartDrawer, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true,
});


However, no mutation is being triggered on iOS devices, everywhere else it works perfectly, including Safari Desktop and Android devices.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any idea why this might be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Than you!
